# Cannot download file name with date format dd/mm/yyyy in html

Tags: html

I need to download a file with the name format like this  `test-dd/mm/yyyy.jpg` but when downloading every forward slash '/' replaced with underscores '_' in file name

**sample code**

```
<h1>The a download attribute</h1>

<p>Click on the image to download it:<p>
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download ="test-22/02/2022.jpg">
  <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

**Note:** The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).

actual value = `test-22_02_2022.jpg`

expected value =  `test-22/02/2022.jpg`

Comment: try escaping the "/" as "\/"

Comment: As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), / and \ are converted to underscores (`_`). Filesystems may forbid other characters in filenames, so browsers will adjust the suggested name if necessary.

Comment: Which operating system are you using that allows / in their filename and filenames to be longer than 16 characters long?